# Spring java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I'm totally a newbie in springs so I wanted to try a helloworld program in springs. I came across [this](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-ide-1.html) tutorial.

I downloaded the source code with library provided on this site, I have the latest Spring STS installed on my Eclipse Kepler. I got this error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.(AbstractApplicationContext.java:153)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.(AbstractApplicationContext.java:217)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:88)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:58)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:61)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:136)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
>           at com.vaannila.HelloWorldApp.main(HelloWorldApp.java:9)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>           ... 8 more

I also tried manually doing the entire program with a different class name and It throws the same error.

Things I have tried:

1. built path and included the springframework jars
2. also included commons-logging-1.1.1.jar

Comment: Please check if your build path contains duplicate commons logging jar

Comment: Does your build path contain `log4j-XXX.jar` library ? If not try to add it. You can download it here http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html

Comment: Tried both of your suggestions, There are no duplicate logging.jars and I added log4j.jar. The error still shows up. Thanks for your fast replies though

Answer (score 0):

I got past this exception by adding commons-logging-1.1.1.jar to the classpath of my project.  I had it in my maven repository from other projects.

Plus, to make the example work, the file name for the instantiation of ClassPathXmlApplicationContext needs to be qualified with the package path.  If you are following the example exactly, you need to instantiate your context like this:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/vaannila/beans.xml");
```